# How can i draw a geomagnetic equator in the basemap as shown in the mention diagram using python?

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

[Code for Drawing Magnetic Equator in basemap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWnzL.jpg)
As I am a beginner, i was trying to add a magnetic equator in the basemap but i was unable to draw even after trying many times. I googled it but couldn't get any idea. So i linked a picture which will help to understand my requirement.

Comment: Please provide all details in your question rather than linking to external resources.

Comment: It is my first question so i was confused while writing my questions.

Comment: That's alright. Just make sure to update your question.